# mongoose subdocument retrieved as String instead of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I have the following objects

```
var Sub = {
  name: String,
};

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  sub: Sub
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

In the database I have the following:

> db.users.find({}).pretty();
>   {
>       "_id" : ObjectId("xyz"),
>       "name" : "John",
>       "sub" : {
>           "name" : "Sub Name"
>       }
>   }

Now, when I query for a user with name "John", the "sub" sub-document is retrieved as a string

typeof user.sub === 'string'

To perform the query I am using User.findById method

```
User.findById("xyz", function(err, user){
  console.log(typeof user.sub);
})
```

Any clues what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type of a field is not defined explicitly, mongoose internal validation will return a sanatized string sometimes. I have solved it by defining a schema in the past.

```
var Sub = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  sub: [ Sub ]
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Please improve your answer because it is currently in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: My apologizes. I learn well from code. I do see your point though!

Comment: already tried that but I am getting an error that I cannot nest schemas. Error "Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays."

Comment: Check my edit when you have a moment. You must put the sub document in an array. This is from the mongoose documentation: "Sub-documents are docs with schemas of their own which are elements of a parent document array" http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: I had already done that originally but in my case there can only be one value for Sub so I wanted to avoid creating a one element array. I guess the only way is to create a one element array?